# Sinon Doesn't Replace Function

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, sinon, stub

I have a function that is being used in a controller;

Im trying to test the catch of the controller calling the endpoint with the supertest.

I'm trying to stub the function with sinon to force it to throw error, but keeps returning http 201 when it should return 500 if the function throws an error. Seems that stub is not working!

Piece of test code:

```js
import * as services from '../../../src/domain/farm/service';

describe('Farm.insertOneController', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    sandbox = Sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should throw error', async () => {
    sandbox.stub(services, 'insertOneFarmService').throws();

    const r = await global.testRequest
      .post('/v1/farms')
      .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      .send({ name: 'Farm1'});

    expect(r.status).toBe(500);
  });
});
```

The function I'm trying to stub:

```js
export const insertOneFarmService = async (f: FarmCreateDTO): Promise<Farm> => {
  return await insertOne(f);
};
```

The index that exports the service:

```js
export * from './insert-one';
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's unknown how insertOneFarmService is related to a place where you expect it to be called. Spying/mocking on `*` import is a mistake, ES modules are read-only by specs, this is what jest.mock is for. *The index that exports the service* - what does it have to do with this? If the function is imported from there and not `farm/service`, it should have mocked there.